# How to pass a data source as Input in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, input, datasource, communication

I have a component, which displays 10 material cards. All of these cards should be able to contain different information. All of that works except of the last thing in the cards: the transactions. I'm trying to implement that with the `@Input()` decorator. But the component with the `@Input()`operator doesn't get any information. 
I already tried to implement the communication between the two components with a service. But then all of the cards got the same transactions in their table. So I'm trying to implement that with `@Input()`right now, to see if it works that way.

Following some code:

Miner-view.component: When I click on a checkbox, it should add the transaction to the current card. That's when the subscription gets called as you can see. `this.blocks[this.minerCounter]`displays the information of the blocks between 1 and 10, depending on the value of `minerCounter`. When I log the value of `this.blocks[this.minerCounter].dataSource.data` I get the right information. But the component with the `@Input()' decorator doesn't get any information.

```
  blocks: Block[] = [];
  blockHash = this.generateFirstHash(); // this method just creates a random string
  transactions: Transaction[];
  previousBlock = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
  blockNumber = 1;
  minerCounter = 1;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  transaction: Transaction;

this.emitTransactionService.row$.subscribe(transaction => {
      if (transaction !== false) {
        this.transaction = transaction;
        this.transactions = this.dataSource.data.slice();
        this.blocks[this.minerCounter].dataSource.data = this.transactions;
        // console.log(this.blocks[this.minerCounter].dataSource.data);
        this.sendMessage4();
        }
        this.ref.detectChanges();
      }
    );

  sendMessage4(): void {
    this.messageService.sendMessage4('Message from miner view component to miner card component!');
  }
```

Miner-card.component:

HTML:

```
<div>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="sender">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sender </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sender}} </td>
        </ng-container>
...
</div>
```

TS: I use `getMessage4()` here, to check if blocks has some value. But it always gives me `null`.

```
      @Input() previousBlock: string;
      transactions: Transaction[] = [];
      @Input() blockHash: string;
      @Input() dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Transaction>;
      @Input() blocks: Block[];

      displayedColumns: string[] = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];

      blockNumber: number;

      message2: any;
      subscription2: Subscription;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private emitTransactionService: EmitTransactionService,
              private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.subscription2 = this.messageService.getMessage4().subscribe(message => {
      this.message2 = message;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      console.log(this.blocks);
    });
  }
```

Following some screenshots:

[image]

When I click on the checkbox, I want the row to be deleted from the "pool" and I want the row to be added in the current card (here card 1).

[image]

Why don't I get `blocks` as Input?

Comment: `@Input() dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Transaction>;` if it is not coming from template binging but from some kind of service,why it is `@Input`?

Comment: It's not coming from a service.

Comment: You removed onInit code na hour ago that says it is coming from Observables callback.